# openmp in Xcode 4.2

Tags: c, xcode4.2, openmp

I just got the latest Xcode 4.2 and I am running into problems with openmp. I have a couple of projects written in C that compiled without any problem with Xcode 3.2.6 but with the new version strange things happen.
One of my projects produces a static library and when I compile it I get this error (not a warning):

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'omp.h' not found
```

I have enabled openmp support and selected the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler. Although I get this error the static library is still generated.

Thinking it could be a conversion problem between 2 different versions of xcode, I created another project with Xcode v4.2 with a simple hello world-like program. I get exactly the same error and the program runs as it should. If I compile this project using the command-line xcodebuild I do not get any error.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, i have exactly the same problem. Not sure this is actually a real problem because the project seems to be correctly compiled.
I'd love to know what's the matter behind that too.

EDIT : finally, there's no error. The problem just comes from the Xcode 4 LLVM engine which shows constantly errors in the editor. And it can't parse the  path. Don't know why.

If you want to get rid of that "error", you can use the direct path instead :

> /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/omp.h

Answer (score 2):

Although the topic is old, I had the same problem with Xcode 5.1.

However, using the direct path doesn't suit for me, because I have to share the code in a developer group.

The problem here is I think, Xcode and the used compiler don't have the same search paths, so Xcode doesn't find the header meanwhile the compiler does. 
I worked around this issue by copying the header to the folder of the set Framework:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include`

This solved the problem for me.